# How many ways are there to color a flag?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can we color a flag with ten stripes using the colors blue, red and yellow, with the adjacent stripes not receiving the same color?

Comment: What are your specific problems with this task? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

$3\cdot 2^9$: $3$ choices for the first stripe, and $2$ choices for each subsequent stripe that cannot be the same color as the previous one.

Comment: Super intuitive answer. +1

Comment: What if you can turn it upside-down? :)